# Token Type Ratio Every 1000 Words

Tags: python, token

I have been asked to calculate the token type ratio of a plain text file gutenberg.txt for every 1000 words. I am then asked to calculate the average token type ratio for the entire file. How would I go about doing this?

This is my code so far:

```
with open ("gutenberg.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
      words = line.split()
      for word in words:
          print (word)
```

From here I need to split the file into 1000 word long strings. I then need to perform ttr() on each string of 1000 words. Here is a link of the html version of the file which I have already cleaned and made plain text in my code: https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1155/1155-h/1155-h.htm

Once I have each of the ttr values for each block of 1000 words, I am asked to average them to calculate the average ttr of the entire file.

Comment: Your question is very vague. What exactly do you means by token type? What does your text file look like? What have you tried already?

Comment: This seems like an interesting problem, but you need to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to be of any help. Otherwise this question is probably going to be closed very quickly.

Comment: What do you want your output to look like? I assume a dict  token-ratio is what you want.

Comment: Yes this is correct